# What is this string: Ôªø and how do I avoid it?

Tags: php, string, invisible

Somehow I managed to stick Ôªø at the top of a PHP script. What is that horrifying group of characters, how could I have entered it, and how can I expose and/or avoid it in the future?

Anecdotally, it was lurking at the very top of a PHP script, before `<?php`. The script needed to send a Content-type header. Because Ôªø pushed the header off the top of the file, the server kept sending its own header, and 2 hours of hilarity ensued. I couldn't even see the string in nano or bash. But I redirected a diff and there it was.

Comment: what is the hex dump of the first few bytes of the file? (`od -t x1 -N 16 file_name.php`)

Comment: 0000000    ef  bb  bf  3c  3f  70  68  70  0d  0a  09  68  65  61  64  65

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's UTF-8 [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (look for EF BB BF). This is a standard thing and shouldn't cause you problems, but if it does then make sure your source code editor doesn't prepend the file with BOM when saving it.

Comment: That was my first thought, too. I suggest converting the file to UTF-8 without BOM and see if that works.

Comment: The “UTF-8 BOM” isn't endorsed by the Unicode standard and as such it is no more than a zero-width-no-break-space when used in this way. Unfortunately many Microsoft tools write these bogus-BOMs to the front of UTF-8 files, breaking them in many tools.

Comment: As a follow-on question, in which encoding does \xEF\xBB\xBF come out to Ôªø? It doesn't seem to match up to any encoding I can find.

Answer (score 4):

That's most certainly an encoding error. Most likely, you're saving your script as one format, but uploading it or declaring it as another. I can't offer any further advice because I don't know much about encoding errors or how to fix them. Good luck squashing the bug.

Comment: +1 These can be a pain to crack.  I've seen version control systems, editors, and differing OS versions all cause them.

Comment: Just checked my local archives and it's there, so that rules out an upload issue. Used Dreamweaver CS4 Mac to edit it, IIRC. Defaults to UTF-8 with Unix endings.